# 2 Instances on Heroku Free Tier?

Tags: heroku, datadog

I have an app with a postgres add on deployed on Heroku free tier. When opening up my integrated Datadog infrastructure list, I expected to see 2 hosts - 1 for the api and one for the db. Instead, I see 3. What is the third?

```
$heroku info
=== myappname
Addons:         heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
Auto Cert Mgmt: false
Dynos:          web: 1, run: 1
Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/myappname.git
Owner:          name@gmail.com
Region:         us
Repo Size:      937 KB
Slug Size:      123 MB
Stack:          heroku-20
Web URL:        https://myappname.herokuapp.com/
```

Not sure what the web and run refers to here.

`heroku regions --common --json` outputs an array of length 2. The machines have 2 different ids. One in Europe, one in the US.

Clicking into the hosts in datadog, I see 2 with info that says dynotype:run and one that says dynotype:web

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had started a 1 off background process (heroku CLI) which is the third machine

Steps to reproduce:

1. `heroku ps`
2. Use the run.wxyz to match with the datadog infrastructure list info

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

I'm still not entirely sure the other node is my db, but that would likely make the most sense.